# unable to produce result in Hadoop: Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to do a job in Hadoop but it seems that I can not produce any result after the job is done. I don't know whether the problem is based on my mapper or reducer. I have two files that contain three columns of data.
here is how my first file looks like:

```
1.1.8.34.28.2   species KKK
1.1.8.34.28.3   species E1
1.1.8.35.32.7   species E1_KKK
1.1.8.36.36.12  species P_KKK
1.1.8.36.36.13  species E2
1.1.8.37.40.17  species E2_P_KKK
1.1.8.38.44.22  species KK
1.1.8.38.44.23  species P_KKK
1.1.8.39.48.27  species P_KKK_KK
1.1.8.40.52.32  species P_KK
1.1.8.40.52.33  species KKPase
1.1.8.41.56.37  species KKPase_P_KK
1.1.8.42.60.42  species P_KK
1.1.8.42.60.43  species P_KKK
1.1.8.43.64.47  species P_KKK_P_KK
1.1.8.44.68.52  species PP_KK
1.1.8.44.68.53  species KKPase
1.1.8.45.72.57  species KKPase_PP_KK
1.1.8.46.76.62  species K
1.1.8.46.76.63  species PP_KK
1.1.8.47.80.67  species PP_KK_K
1.1.8.48.84.72  species P_K
1.1.8.48.84.73  species KPase
1.1.8.49.88.77  species KPase_P_K
1.1.8.50.92.82  species P_K
1.1.8.50.92.83  species PP_KK
1.1.8.51.96.87  species PP_KK_P_K
1.1.8.52.100.92 species PP_K
1.1.8.52.100.93 species KPase
1.1.8.53.104.97 species KPase_PP_K
```

and my second file looks like this:

```
1.1.8.34.29.4   species E1_KKK
1.1.8.35.33.8   species E1
1.1.8.35.33.9   species P_KKK
1.1.8.36.37.14  species E2_P_KKK
1.1.8.37.41.18  species E2
1.1.8.37.41.19  species KKK
1.1.8.38.45.24  species P_KKK_KK
1.1.8.39.49.28  species P_KK
1.1.8.39.49.29  species P_KKK
1.1.8.40.53.34  species KKPase_P_KK
1.1.8.41.57.38  species KK
1.1.8.41.57.39  species KKPase
1.1.8.42.61.44  species P_KKK_P_KK
1.1.8.43.65.48  species PP_KK
1.1.8.43.65.49  species P_KKK
1.1.8.44.69.54  species KKPase_PP_KK
1.1.8.45.73.58  species P_KK
1.1.8.45.73.59  species KKPase
1.1.8.46.77.64  species PP_KK_K
1.1.8.47.81.68  species P_K
1.1.8.47.81.69  species PP_KK
1.1.8.48.85.74  species KPase_P_K
1.1.8.49.89.78  species K
1.1.8.49.89.79  species KPase
1.1.8.50.93.84  species PP_KK_P_K
1.1.8.51.97.88  species PP_KK
1.1.8.51.97.89  species PP_K
1.1.8.52.101.94 species KPase_PP_K
1.1.8.53.105.98 species P_K
1.1.8.53.105.99 species KPase
```

the expected output is equal to:

```
1.1.8.35    E1_KKK   
1.1.8.36    E2   
1.1.8.36    P_KKK    
1.1.8.38    KK   
1.1.8.38    P_KKK    
1.1.8.39    P_KKK_KK     
1.1.8.40    KKPase   
1.1.8.40    P_KK     
1.1.8.42    P_KK     
1.1.8.42    P_KKK    
1.1.8.43    P_KKK_P_KK   
1.1.8.44    KKPase   
1.1.8.44    PP_KK    
1.1.8.45    KKPase_PP_KK     
1.1.8.46    K    
1.1.8.46    PP_KK    
1.1.8.47    PP_KK_K  
1.1.8.50    PP_KK    
1.1.8.50    P_K  
1.1.8.51    PP_KK_P_K
```

When I run the job on Hadoop, I receive nothing as a result. I am stuck at this part and can not figure out where my problem is.
Below I have attached my mappers.

```
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String[] mySplittedValue=value.toString().split("\\s+"); 
      String id=mySplittedValue[0]; 
      String valueOfSpieces=mySplittedValue[2];
      if(mySplittedValue[1].equals("species") && valueOfSpieces.contains("P_KK")) {
        int myId=id.lastIndexOf(".");
        String myVal=(id.substring(0,myId)).substring(0,((id.substring(0,myId).lastIndexOf("."))));
        TextPair myKey= new TextPair(myVal, valueOfSpieces); 
        context.write(myKey, new Text(this.getClass().getName()));
          
      }
```

```
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String[] mySplittedValue=value.toString().split("\\s+");
      String id=mySplittedValue[0];
      String valueOfSpieces=mySplittedValue[2];
      if(mySplittedValue[1].equals("species")) {
        int myId=id.lastIndexOf(".");
        String myVal=(id.substring(0,myId)).substring(0,((id.substring(0,myId).lastIndexOf("."))));
        TextPair myKey= new TextPair(myVal, valueOfSpieces);   
        context.write(myKey, new Text(this.getClass().getName()));  
      } 
  }
```

and this is my reducer:

```
 protected void reduce(TextPair key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      boolean checkMatch = false;
      String valueOfContext;
      Iterator myIteratorOverContext = context.getValues().iterator();
      List<String> myMapperValue = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (myIteratorOverContext.hasNext()) {
            myIteratorOverContext.next();
          if (context.getCurrentValue().toString().equals(JoinMapper1.class.getName())) {
              checkMatch = true;
          } else {
              myMapperValue.add(context.getCurrentKey().toString());
          }
        }
        if (checkMatch) {
          for(String item : myMapperValue) {
            context.write(new Text(item), new Text(" "));
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please add log statements to print out data in your job when you expect data is written. If you get no output, your conditional statements are filtering everything out

Comment: Do you mean that my reducer has a problem?  Or, it may be the problem of my mapper? I don't know how should I fix it since this is my first time that I run a job on Hadoop and I am entirely new in this field.

Comment: If you're completely new, then I'll tell you that no one really writes mapreduce code. Spark is far more popular. In any case, both could have a problem. Add System.out.println lines, then look at the job logs to see where things go wrong. You can also use Junit tests to ensure your logic is actually correct